# Joining Posts with Comments in the BigQuery Reddit dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, reddit

How are the `comments` and `posts` tables related in the Reddit dataset available on [BigQuery](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/3cej2b/17_billion_reddit_comments_loaded_on_bigquery/)?
It doesn't seem obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT posts.title, comments.body
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_01` AS comments
JOIN `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_01`  AS posts
ON posts.id = SUBSTR(comments.link_id, 4) 
WHERE posts.id = '43go1r'
```

If you still using BigQuery Legacy SQL consider [`migrating to BigQuery Standard SQL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Btw, performance wise it took 2 sec vs. 18 sec in Legacy SQL

Comment: Note for others who are unfamiliar (as I was): the Standard SQL syntax this answer uses is in the \`\`'s around the table names. Thanks Mikhail.

Comment: Another Note: to turn off Legacy SQL in the BigQuery query composer, click on 'Show Options' and uncheck the 'Use Legacy SQL' box.

Answer (score 1):

Using the advice from [u/Infamous_Blue](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/7hznl3/update_reddit_daily_submission_and_comment_file/dsaln61/), we can join comments to their parent posts by using `SUBSTR()` on the column `link_id` and matching it with the post's `id`. For example, each comment will have a `link_id` looking something like `t3_43go1r`, so to match the post's `id` of `43go1r` we must call `SUBSTR(link_id, 4)`.

Here is a complete query where we join the post's `title` with each comments `body`:

```
select posts.title, comments.body --grab anything you like
from (select SUBSTR(link_id, 4) as lnk, body 
      from [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01]) as comments,
join [fh-bigquery:reddit_posts.2016_01]  as posts
on posts.id = comments.lnk
where posts.id = '43go1r'; --random subreddit
```

This completed in 40.3 seconds and processed 11.9 GB when ran.

Comment: Predicates are not "pushed down" through joins automatically when using legacy SQL, so using standard SQL instead is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks. Still new to bigquery. I've selected the answer from Mikhail which uses the standard syntax.

Comment: No worries! If you're interested in trying the refreshed BigQuery UI that uses standard SQL by default, you can [submit this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf6hyfvoWZ8eUbbKWq9fzVfj7ljVyl2SdhtWH038Xrx2eHVrw/viewform?usp=send_form).